# Gradient with respect to a matrix variable

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, tensors

I want to find the gradient of the function $\mathcal{F}_1$ with respect to the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ (differentiate with respect to $\mathbf{X}$):

$$
\mathcal{F}_1 (\mathbf{X}; \mathbf{\lambda})= \Upsilon (\mathbf{X}; \mathbf{\lambda}) - \log \mathcal{C}_{\rho}(\mathbf{X})
$$

where:

- $\mathbf{X}=[\mathbf{A}^T, \mathbf{B}^T, \mathbf{S}^T]^T$, $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C}^{I \times R}$, $\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{C}^{J \times R}$, $\mathbf{S}\in \mathbb{C}^{K \times R}$
- the vector $\mathbf{\lambda} \in \mathbb{C}^{R}$
- $\Upsilon(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{\lambda}) = \Upsilon(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{S}; \mathbf{\lambda}) = \Vert \mathbf{T}- [\mathbf{\lambda}; \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{S}]\Vert^2 $

  where $[\mathbf{\lambda}; \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{S}]$ represent the $3$-tensor defined by:
  $$\sum_{r=1}^{R} \lambda_r(\mathbf{a}_r \circ \mathbf{b}_r \circ \mathbf{s}_r) $$ 
  with $\mathbf{a}_r$ represent the the column $r$ of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, the same thing for $\mathbf{b}_r$ and $\mathbf{s}_r$; "$\circ$" denotes the outer product.

  $\mathbf{T}$ is a given $3$-tensor with norm $\| \mathbf{T}\|^2 = \sum\limits_{ijk} |T_{ijk}|^2$
- $\mathcal{C}_{\rho}(\mathbf{X})= \mathcal{C}_{\rho}(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{S}) = $ $$\frac{1}{(2R+2)^2}-\left(\sum_{q<p}|\mathbf{a}_{p}^H \mathbf{a}_{q}|^{2\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}} -\left(\sum_{q<p}|\mathbf{b}_{p}^H \mathbf{b}_{q}|^{2\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}-\left(\sum_{q<p}|\mathbf{s}_{p}^H \mathbf{s}_{q}|^{2\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}$$

Can you help me please or give me some docs?

Answer (score 1):

The infinite matrices can be treated as functions and I see that the most appropriate treatment is the use of nonlinear functional analysis.

I do not see how the calculations difficult conceptually. But surely they needed some ten pages of calculations at least.

Use the definition of derivative Frechet and explore the chain rule and the linearity of its infinite matrices. See in [Home Page of Gerald Teschl](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/index.html) (in 'Lecture Notes' section )   the excelente book of [nonlinear functional analysis.](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-nlfa/nlfa.pdf). It's a free book for dowload.

See too [Banach Spaces and Differential Calculus](http://www.univalle.edu.co/~juancamg/Banach2.pdf).